# How to Filter multidimensional array and create a new array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have this kind of array  , based on Page ID like : 32,143.

I want to search if array key `position` have **both** value in it , then ignore **prepend** and **append** value and consider **ONLY** **both** value.

And if the array has **NO** **both** value and multiple **prepend** and **append** value, then it will consider based on `priority` key.

```
$sort_result = Array
(
    [32] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [page] => 32
                    [position] => append
                    [priority] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [page] => 32
                    [position] => append
                    [priority] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [page] => 32
                    [position] => prepend
                    [priority] => 3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [page] => 32
                    [position] => both
                    [priority] => 3
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [page] => 32
                    [position] => prepend
                    [priority] => 4
                )

        )

    [143] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [page] => 143
                    [position] => prepend
                    [priority] => 19
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [page] => 143
                    [position] => prepend
                    [priority] => 18
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [page] => 143
                    [position] => append
                    [priority] => 18
                )

        )

)
```

I tried the following code , but not working :

```
<?php 
foreach ( $modify_array as $key => $value ) {
    foreach( $value as $k1 => $v1) {
        if ( array_search( "both", $v1 ) ) {
            $final_array[$key][$k1] = $v1;
        } else{
            if ( array_search( "prepend", $v1 ) ) {
                $final_array[$key][$k1] = $v1;
            }
            if ( array_search( "append", $v1 ) ) {
                $final_array[$key][$k1] = $v1;
            }
           
        }
     break;
    }
}
```

I am expecting output like this :

```
Array
(
    [32] => Array
        (
            
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [page] => 32
                    [position] => both
                    [priority] => 3
                )

        )

    [143] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [page] => 143
                    [position] => prepend
                    [priority] => 18
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [page] => 143
                    [position] => append
                    [priority] => 18
                )

        )

)
```

**EDIT 1  :**

I manage to work , using this code

```
$modify_array = array();
foreach ( $sort_result as $sort_result_key => $sort_result_value ) {  
    $modify_array[$sort_result_value['page']][] = $sort_result_value;
}

foreach ( $modify_array as $key => $value ) {

    $filter_array[$key]['both_yes'] = array_keys(array_column($value, 'position'),'both');
    $filter_array[$key]['prepend_yes'] = array_keys( array_column($value, 'position'),'prepend');
    $filter_array[$key]['append_yes'] = array_keys(array_column($value, 'position'),'append');

} 
    

foreach ( $filter_array as $filter_array_key => $filter_array_value ) {
    if ( ! empty( $filter_array_value['both_yes'])) {
        $a = $filter_array_value['both_yes'][0];
        $final_array[] = $modify_array[$filter_array_key][$a];
        
    } else {
        if ( ! empty( $filter_array_value['prepend_yes'])) {
            $b = $filter_array_value['prepend_yes'][0];
            $final_array[] = $modify_array[$filter_array_key][$b];
        }
        if ( ! empty( $filter_array_value['append_yes'])) {
            $c = $filter_array_value['append_yes'][0];
            $final_array[] = $modify_array[$filter_array_key][$c];
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2 : `var_export`**

```
 array ( 32 => array ( 0 => array ( 'page' => '32', 'position' => 'append', 'priority' => '1', ), 1 => array ( 'page' => '32', 'position' => 'append', 'priority' => '2', ), 2 => array ( 'page' => '32', 'position' => 'prepend', 'priority' => '3', ), 3 => array ( 'page' => '32', 'position' => 'both', 'priority' => '3', ), 4 => array ( 'page' => '32', 'position' => 'prepend', 'priority' => '4', ), ), 143 => array ( 0 => array ( 'page' => '143', 'position' => 'prepend', 'priority' => '18', ), 1 => array ( 'page' => '143', 'position' => 'append', 'priority' => '18', ), 2 => array ( 'page' => '143', 'position' => 'prepend', 'priority' => '19', ), ), )
```

Comment: Can you please provide your input array in a form we can use directly (var_export, or as JSON.)

Comment: @cbroe I didn't get you.

Comment: Your example array above is not given in the form of valid PHP code, so everyone trying to test your code or write an alternative for you, would have to modify it first. If you show us the result of a `var_export` instead, that would be valid PHP code we can use via copy&paste right away.

Comment: @cbroe
In my code , I am getting the exact output that I want. Because , Already I have set array as per priority. ( Check 1st `print_r` array , I have posted )
But I feel , I have used foreach loop many time.
You can check ***Edit 1 :*** in my question , for the code , I am using now.

Comment: `print_r()` output is annoying for volunteers.   Please post your sample input as `var_export()` as CBroe said twice.

Comment: Could there ever be more than one `both` entry for a relative `page`?  We might not have a large enough [mcve].  The `working` code in your is using a lot of loops; I'd like to try to craft a more efficient solution.

Comment: @cbroe and @mickmackusa

Added `var_export` in ***Edit : 2*** , is this what you are asking ?

Comment: Yes @mickmackusa

There may be more than one `both` for a relative page.
If so ,I will use , which have Highest priority.
Priority Calculation : ( 1 - Highest , 10 - Lowest )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the lowest time complexity that I can boil this task down to uses 1 full loop of your input array followed by a loop of the grouped data with a nested loop to isolate the rows with the lowest priority value.

The first loop does the grouping and potentially sheds worthless `non-both` rows for a trivial memory savings.

The second loop iterates the `page` groups, then the inner loop favors `both` rows and only uses `non-both` rows if there are no `both` rows. The `if` and `elseif` ensure that only the rows with the lowest priority number are retained.  I added a `rsort()` call with the assumption that you want `prepend` rows before `append` rows.  If the position values don't need to be prioritized, then omit the condition block containing the `rsort()` call.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IuNCF))

```
$array = [
    ['page' => '32', 'position' => 'append', 'priority' => '1'],
    ['page' => '32', 'position' => 'append', 'priority' => '2'],
    ['page' => '32', 'position' => 'prepend', 'priority' => '3'],
    ['page' => '32', 'position' => 'both', 'priority' => '3'],
    ['page' => '32', 'position' => 'prepend', 'priority' => '4'],
    ['page' => '143', 'position' => 'prepend', 'priority' => '18'],
    ['page' => '143', 'position' => 'append', 'priority' => '18'],
    ['page' => '143', 'position' => 'prepend', 'priority' => '19'],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['page']])) {
        $result[$row['page']] = ['both' => [], 'non-both' => []];
    }
    if ($row['position'] !== 'both') {
        if ($result[$row['page']]['both']) {
            continue; // nothing worth doing in this case, ignore the row
        } else {
            $result[$row['page']]['non-both'][] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $result[$row['page']]['both'][] = $row;
    }
}

foreach ($result as $page => $rows) {
    $keep = [];
    foreach ($rows['both'] ?: $rows['non-both'] as $row) {
        if (!$keep || $row['priority'] < $keep[0]['priority']) {
            $keep = [$row];
        } elseif ($row['priority'] === $keep[0]['priority']) {
            $keep[] = $row;
        }
    }
    if ($keep[0]['position'] !== 'both') {
        rsort($keep);  // assuming you need prepend to occur before append
    }
    $result[$page] = $keep;
}
var_export($result);
```